# Reverse proxy via Passenger/Nginx on Heroku

Tags: heroku, nginx, proxy

I have Rails app on Heroku and need to create a reverse proxy to our blog, which is currently hosted on dreamhost. It was originally hosted at blog.ourdomain.com but we now want ourdomain.com/blog to point to it. From my research it seems like the best to do this is a reverse proxy via the Nginx component of our Passenger application server. So, I've created a location in our `nginx.conf.erb`:

```
    location ^~ /blog {
        proxy_pass https://blog.ourdomain.com;
    }
```

This works just fine for our purposes, EXCEPT when `/blog` is visited. (`/blog/`, `/blog/whatever/...` is fine).

When `/blog` is used, nginx instead  redirects to  `ourdomain.com:12345/blog/` where the port is what I assume to be our heroku dyno's port. How can I get the slash-less URI to go reverse proxy correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem as well. We still haven't gotten our proxy fully functioning - running into some weird redirect loops on the WordPress / Apache side - but we did solve this by manually setting the port:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_pass https://blog.ourdomain.com:80;
}
```

I'm not confident enough in my nginx knowledge to say that will work for sure, but it seems to be working for us.